# Want to get rid of extra python installations ( MAC Mojave)

Tags: uninstall, python3

I have two Python 3 installations with following paths.

1. /Library/Framsworks/Python.Frameworks/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
2. /usr/local/bin/python3

Should I remove the  one of them? if so which one? if so, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[Python 3 installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chhGE.png)

Comment: *"Should I remove the one of them?"* -- Unless you are *absolutely certain* that you personally installed a particular installation, I would be wary of doing this. While Python 3 is typically installed manually on Mac (at least, this seems to have been the case under six months ago, as of the time of this writing), it's certainly plausible these may be used by one or more items on your system (think e.g. applications you've installed here).